# Confused with XML Parsing in Python

Tags: python, xml, android-manifest

Im Working on a little application for Android Development in Python and i need to Parse the AndroidManifest.xml to know the different activites and fetch their "roles" in the application , especially the Startup (LAUNCHER) activities
Here is an example of a dummy AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application>
        <activity android:name="com.vine.vox.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.vine.vox.About">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NOT_REALLY"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.GO_AHEAD"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.vine.vox.DeadStuff">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEAD"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.SOMETHING_DEAD"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

What i need from this is to spot Which activity has `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>`

And the Location of the Activity from `<activity android:name="Activity Location">`

In that example the Activity i want would be `<activity android:name="com.vine.vox.MainActivity">` since its the activity which has `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>`

I've Tried ElementTree , Minidom , LXML , But i still dont understand how it can really be done , i even tried to the old fashioned Text Parsing but i need the Tool to work on any AndroidManifest.xml the user wants and that came out to be a problem.

Sorry for the long post , any help i get is appreciated !

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in a few lines using `lxml` and the following XPath :

```
//activity[
    .//category/@android:name = 'android.intent.category.LAUNCHER'
]/@android:name
```

The above XPath expression reads : find `<activity>` element containing `<category>` element where `android:name` attribute value equals 'android.intent.category.LAUNCHER', and then return `android:name` of the found `activity`.

Notice that you'll need to define *prefix to namespace URI* mapping to be able to use prefix (like 'android' in the following example) in your XPath :

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("your_xml_file.xml")
ns = {'android' : 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'}

query = "//activity[.//category/@android:name = 'android.intent.category.LAUNCHER']/@android:name"

result = tree.xpath(query, namespaces=ns)

print result[0]
```

**output :**

```
com.vine.vox.MainActivity
```

Comment: AWESOME ! That did it for me , Nice and clean , Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
from __future__ import print
import xml.sax

class AndroidManifestHandler(xml.sax.ContentHandler):
    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        if name == 'category':
            attr = attrs.get('android:name')
            print('Category: {0}'.format(attr))
        elif name == 'activity':
            attr = attrs.get('android:name')
            print('Name: {0}'.format(attr)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I dont really know how to use xml.sax so i couldnt really test

Comment: No worries, @Zylva, long as your problem's sorted, it's cool.